# Крон не запускается и/или не успевает отработать за указанное время.

Tags: php, linux

У меня есть крон, который каждый час запускает некий php-скрипт.

Q: Скажите, пожалуйста, если скрипт не успел выполнится за час, крон запуститься другим потоком или нет?

Дело в том, что у меня по каким-то причинам не запустился (

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот например строка в crontab

```
*/1 * * * *  sleep 300
```

через некоторое время я получаю:

```
26709 ?        Ss     0:00 sleep 30026735 ?        Ss     0:00 sleep 300
```

возможно ваш скрипт имеет свои lock файлы, или сам по себе ограничен во времени запуска.

Comment: Не совсем понял, но кажется, направление верное. Можно чуть по-подробнее?

Comment: подробнее можно сказать при просмотре данного php-скрипта

Answer (score 0):

В другой теме уже ответил, что это можно, если скрипт запускать в бэкграунде (со значом амперсанда - "&" через пробел после). С одним-единственным "но" - если сама прога или скрипт не препятствует наличию нескольких своих копий в процессах.